# host context not working in the angular 8 when pass template to the modal component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I have alert component that there is template in it , and I pass this template to the modal service and I want to set style for alert component for rtl and ltr ,rtl and ltr are as className in the body tag

alert.component.html

```
<ng-template #test >
  <div class="message" >
    <div>this is message</div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

alert.component.ts

```
 ...
 ///
  @ViewChild('alert',{static:true}) alert:Template<any>
  /// some code
  this.modal.open(this.alert).then(()=>{
  })
```

alert.component.scss

```
.message{
 color:green;
}
::host-context .rtl{
  .message{
   color:red;
 }
}
```

but I inspect i haven't see any .rtl.message css class , it seems that host context not working because of template

Comment: can you make a stackblitz example? https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

try the following :

```
:host-context(.rtl) .message { 
    color:red;
}
```

**[Stackblitz Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/host-context-angular)**